# How to join two dataframe in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to join two dataframe using python. I am attaching Book.xls file for reference. In that file we have two columns in sheet 1 as System_requirement_linked and other column as OH_Requirement linked. In the other sheet we have one column as System_Requiremnet_liknked containing the same data as both of the columns of sheet 1. I want to merge those data of sheet 1 with sheet 2 and print the final result sheet with all the corresponding data available in the sheet. In general i have both the sheet in different folder and not in a Book form.

[image: Sheet_1]

[image: Sheet_2]

Comment: Do you want to merge data from two sheets of the same excel file or do you want to merge two different excel files?

Comment: I want to merge data from two different excel files.

Comment: And you have same 2 columns in those excel files?

Comment: Yes...But actually i have 2 different columns in sheet 1 with name specified as (a&b)  and 1 columns in sheet 2 specified as name(a). I have attached the snippet for the same,

Comment: So, you want to perform Join on the basis of that common column, right?

Comment: I need to the data from both the column from the sheet_1(a&b) and match with the data of column of sheet_2 (a). So my input will be column (a&b) from sheet 1 and column (a) from sheet 2, and i need the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets name your sheets - sheet_1 & sheet_2. Now sheet_1 has 2 columns  & sheet_2 has 1 column. Now you want merge these 2 sheets based on specific column which exists in both the sheets. If my understanding is correct, then below is the answer

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel("Path_to_excel.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet_name")
df2 = pd.read_excel("Path_to_excel2.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet_name")

df1 = df1[['Column_1', 'Column_2']]
df2 = df2[['Column_1']]

df = df1.merge(df2, on='Column_1', how='left') # if you need all entries of df1
```

or

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Column_1', how='right') # if you need all entries of df2
```

or

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Column_1', how='outer') # if you need all entries of both df1 & df2
```

or

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Column_1') # if you need all entries that exists in both dataframes
```

Thats it TaDa!!

Comment: No I have columns (1 & 2) in sheet 1 with some data and the same data i have in sheet 2 in column 1. I want to compare and merge data on the basis of input from both the column(1 & 2) of sheet 1 and compare it with sheet 2 (column 1).

Comment: You mean to say, the column_1 of sheet_2 has data of both columns of sheet_1. If that's the case, you need to merge twice
`df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='Column_1')` and `df4 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='Column_2'), right_on='Column_1')` and finally append both dataframes
`df = df3.append(df4, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Thanks for the above.....One more query-> If u see my attachments above in that i want to achieve the result that when the data in column 1 of the sheet 1 matches the data of column 1 of sheet 2 then we need to print the final result with all the corresponding data and ignoring the data of column 1 of sheet 2 printing again. The same i want to follow for the column 2. Please suggest the step for that scenario.

Comment: That's simple, lets consider the final dataframe is ready and is named as `df`
`data = df[['col1', 'col2']][df['col1'] == 'value']`. In this case, if you print `data`, you will get two columns of final dataframe of matching rows.

Please accept my answer, if you its solved your problem

Comment: Here value is referred to?

Comment: `value` is referred to your values of column 1 of sheet 2, which can be written as 

`df2['column_1'].unique()`, so in this case your final statement would be

`data = df[['col1', 'col2']][df['col1'].isin(df2['column_1'].unique())`

Comment: If i want to delete a column where the index number is getting printed but the column is without any column name, then how i can do that?

Comment: Try this `print(df.to_string(index=False))` and Do accept answer if it solved your problem

Comment: But yet, you did not accept the above as answer. I'm Glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can merge two Dataframes in Pandas using `pd.concat()` method. You've to pass a list of the dataframes that you want to merge.

Following is the code to merge the two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/stackoverflow/egSheet1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/stackoverflow/egSheet2.xlsx')

#create a list of all frames in order to append them
frameList = [df1, df2]

#append the dataframes
appendedDf = pd.concat(frameList)
```